# Regex replace only groups

Tags: regex, racket

I really do not understand how regex works in racket.
Provided we have the code below

```
(regexp-replace #px"\\((.*)\\)\\/\\((.*)\\)"
                "(A + B)/(C)"
                "\\\\dfrac\\{\\1\\}\\{\\2\\}")
```

expected result should be `\dfrac{A + B}{C}`. The same works correct e.g. in python. Nonetheless, I get `\dfrac(A + B)/(C){A + B(A + B)/(C)}(A + B)/(C){C(A + B)/(C)}`. I can even feel some logic behind that. Maybe the case is in how match behaves, since `regexp-match` returns list of three elements when applied to this regex and string: `'("(A + B)/(C)" "A + B" "C")`. Or maybe I should use sth instead of `regex-replace`?

How can I achieve what I want and, more importantly, how to understand the logic behind racket's regex without pushing through all the documentation?

Comment: You don't need to escape `{` in the replacement string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `\\{` in the replacement string. `{` doesn't need to be escaped in the replacement, only in a regular expression. And the documentation says:

> If a `\` in *insert* is followed by anything other than a digit, `&`, `\`, or `$`, then the `\` by itself is treated as `\0`.

So each `\\{` gets replaced with the entire match.

The correct call is

```
(regexp-replace #px"\\((.*)\\)\\/\\((.*)\\)"
                "(A + B)/(C)"
                "\\\\dfrac{\\1}{\\2}")
```

See [DEMO](https://ideone.com/ux5Bol)

Comment: I see. So we escape what they don't escape and vice versa) The most ironic thing is that regex in elisp is also different from the other world, but it's different from racket too... Why are there so many regexes... Thanks for your reply, everything works fine!

Comment: There are many different regexp flavors, due to history of different tools.